# Get_account with Python

Tags: cleos, accounts, api, python

After reading the [documentation](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/chain_api_plugin/api-reference/index) about EOS APIs, I tried to get information about an account on the blockchain by following examples and docs. However it's not working and I really don't understand why. This is my Python code:

```
import requests # Requests: HTTP for Humans

url = "https://api.eosn.io/v1/chain/get_account"
data = {"account": "yupcreators1"}
r = requests.post(url, data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

This is the response error I get:

```
500
{"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":4,"name":"parse_error_exception","what":"Parse Error","details":[{"message":"Unexpected char '97' in \"account\"","file":"json.cpp","line_number":436,"method":"variant_from_stream"},{"message":"","file":"json.cpp","line_number":459,"method":"from_string"}]}}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 'account_name' instead of 'account', and json needs to be dumped.

```python
import requests, json

url = "https://api.eosn.io/v1/chain/get_account"
data = {"account_name": "yupcreators1"}
r = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data))
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: The `account` instead of `account_name` was my mistake when copying the code here, I didn't know I had to dump the data because with the other methods it worked just fine. It works now, thanks a lot.